# Is there any problem in pronunciation of words with Phonetic Alphabet?

Tags: phonetics

I have pronounced the English words with Phonetic Alphabet(in the site ldoceonline.com) for almost 1500 words and I have improved very well. But I didn't see anyone that uses this method for a large number of words. Can I continue this method for the pronunciation of English words and can I improve?

Comment: Most dictionaries use the broad transcription, which merely uses phonemes. Every phoneme has its own realization or alophone; for example, /p/ may be realized by the aspirated bilabial stop; /t/ may be realized by the glottal stop. Other words, the dictionary transcriptions are abstract and do not represent the *actual* pronunciations used native speakers. This question, anyways, would be closed as it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Thank you. But learning pronunciation by Alphabet is very faster for me. Can I say: "there is a little difference between Alphabet Phonetic and the actual pronunciation and I can correct these differences later" ??

Comment: The difference is not 'little'. If you want to study the pronunciation with the IPA, I suggest you use Wiktionary. Wiktionary uses the narrow transcription, which includes all the diacritics.